# How to performance test an Update endpoint in JMeter while automatically updating row value in payload

Tags: api, .net-core, jmeter, microservices, performance-testing

I have an Update entity endpoint in my .NET Core Microservice API that needs to be tested for performance. For all other endpoints, I am able to store the ID in a CSV file and load it before processing, however I want to reuse the values in the CSV for update, which requires updating and keeping track of the Row Version attribute for the ID.

I will be testing using 100 Users and 100 Orders, so I will need to match every user to one order so they don't try updating the same entity.

Steps:

1. Read CSV with ID and current row version
2. Call Update endpoint on the ID and row version, read in new Row Version from response body
3. Store the new row version and the ID within JMeter to reuse in the test
4. Call Update endpoint on the ID and new row version

The problem with storing inside of the CSV is JMeter will be reading and writing from the same file. I am looking for a way to use a Java like collection inside of my script to not have to read and write from a file.

The dictionary would look like {'q28937-3423572903485-324875', rowVersion: 42}

Comment: Have you tried one of Jmeter's pre/post processors ?

Comment: I will be testing using 100 Users and 100 Orders, so I will need to match every user to one order so they don't try updating the same entity

Comment: I have tried the pre/post processors but can't put together how it should function

Comment: So you are hitting an endpoint to update a row version, and you want to extract the new row version from the response of this endpoint, save it as a jmeter variable and use it to update the row version again... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: Can it be done for more than one record?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as a child of your HTTP request (the first update) to extract the new ID and rowVersion.

Then in the next update, you should use Jmeter variables `${ID}` and `${rowVersion}` which holds the new values that you extracted using Post Processor.

Note that variables are not shared between threads, from [Jmeter user manual best practices - 16.13](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

> Variables are local to a thread; a variable set in one thread cannot be read in another. This is by design.

Also check

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) guide.
- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guide.
- [CSV data set config Jmeter User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: How do the variables know the value of the specific thread that is running?

Comment: As i mentioned above, by design, the variables are linked to threads that created the variables. So if **thread 1** created a var ID with value **123** and **thread 2** created var ID with value **456**, whenever **thread 1** calls var ID, the value will be **123**, and for **thread 2** the value will be **456**.

Comment: How will I loop through the CSV file and set each record to its own thread variable?

Comment: ^ at the beginning of the test

Comment: I'm assuming you are using **CSV Data Set Config** to read from the csv file. Now this element is also designed that each thread will read a different row from the file. So thread 1 will read row 1 and thread 2 will read row 2...etc. I updated the answer with links related ti this element.